# Wechat applet, two buttons expand at the same time

Tags: javascript, wechat

Two buttons in one page:

- button A contains two sub_button c and d
- button B contains two
  sub_button e and f

When user

- press button A ,sub_button c and d should get expanded
- press button B ,sub_button e and f should get expanded

But now when i press button A or B all sub_button expand, while A B should not affect each other.

```
<view class="bg-white" wx:for="{{ dataInfo }}" wx:key="item">
    <view class="data-info" data-idx="{{ index }}" bindtap="expandDetail">
        <view>
            <button class="aaa" disabled="{{disabled}}" bindtap='submit'>
                <text>AAA</text>
            </button>
        </view>
    </view>
    <!-- 展开 -->
    <view class="data-expand p10 border-bottom" wx:if="{{ item.flag }}">
        <button class="ccc" type="warn">ccc</button>
        <button class="ddd" type="warn">ddd</button>
    </view>
</view>
<view class="bg-white" wx:for="{{ dataInfo }}" wx:key="item">
    <view class="data-info" data-idx="{{ index }}" bindtap="expandDetail">
        <view>
            <button class="bbb" disabled="{{disabled}}" bindtap='submit'>
                <text>BBB</text>
            </button>
        </view>
    </view>
    <!-- 展开 -->
    <view class="data-expand p10 border-bottom" wx:if="{{ item.flag }}">
        <button class="eee" type="warn">eee</button>
        <button class="fff" type="warn">fff</button>
    </view>
</view>
```

```
 Page({
    data: {
        tempInfo: [{}, ],
        dataInfo: [],
    },
    expandDetail: function (e) {
        var idx = e.currentTarget.dataset.idx,
        key = "dataInfo[" + idx + "].flag",
        val = this.data.dataInfo[idx].flag;
        this.setData({
            [key]: !val
        });
    },
    onLoad: function (opt) {
        for (var i in this.data.tempInfo) {
            this.data.tempInfo[i].flag = false;
        };
        this.setData({
            dataInfo: this.data.tempInfo
        });
    },
 })
```

Comment: //javascript




Page({


  data: {
    tempInfo: [{
    }, ],
    dataInfo: [], 
},






  expandDetail: function (e) {
    var idx = e.currentTarget.dataset.idx, 
        key = "dataInfo[" + idx + "].flag",
        val = this.data.dataInfo[idx].flag;
    this.setData({
      [key]: !val
    });
  },


  onLoad: function(opt) {
    for (var i in this.data.tempInfo) {
      this.data.tempInfo[i].flag = false; 
    };
    this.setData({
      dataInfo: this.data.tempInfo
    });
  },



})

Comment: damn javascript can not send